# How to write a Team Build Process Template (2010) from scratch?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I know `DefaultTemplate.xaml` does everything needed. But I gonna learn team build this by creating an entire new build process from scratch. I need to know which activities must be included, in which order and so on. This must be using WF in Team Build 2010.

Many Thanks in Advance

**UPDATE:**

I found this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181715.aspx) in MSDN that describes build definitions completely, but does not contain anything about `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities` namespace.

**UPDATE 2:**

I found a [similar question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsbuild/thread/f7aa63d2-5e72-42a3-a805-97ae053da20d) in the MSDN Forums.

**UPDATE 3:**
Found a [link](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/04/20/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-1-Introduction.aspx) titled "Customize Team Build 2010". But this does not help more too.

Comment: I wrote a blog post about my total experience with versioning in Team Build 2010: http://afsharm.blogspot.com/2010/07/versioning-assemblies-with-team-build.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the upgrade template. If you remove the MSBuild activity, you're fairly close to a minimal build workflow that still supports gated check-ins, etc.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what do you mean. Upgrade Template Progress is very similar to Template Progress.

Comment: You'll find UpgradeTemplate.xaml in the same version control folder  as DefaultTemplate.xaml. It's the build process template that's used for build definitions migrated from earlier versions of TFS. In the upgrade template, the majority of the build process is driven by MSBuild rather than WF, so the template is much simpler.

Comment: Yes, `UpgradeTemplate` is very simpler. Thanks Jim.